# How to make a graphql mutation without parameters? (Vue Apollo)

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I have a vue app where I am toggling the width of a sidebar menu. My plan is to have a UI object in a local apollo cache where i can keep track of various UI states (ex. sidebar open vs. closed). I have a query to check the state of the sidebar and a mutation to update it. But for some reason the mutation seems to require that i give it parameters ($id: ID), even though I'm not actually passing anything to the mutation when I use it. How should i write the mutation when i'm not using any parameters? Or is a parameter required? Attempts at removing parameters and corresponding error messages below.

[image: Code:]

Removing parameters from both like so (Attempt #1):

[image]

Results in:

[image: Error Message:]

Removing parenthesis like so (Attempt #2):

[image]

Results in:

[image]

Comment: "Seems to require that i give it parameters"... meaning when you don't, you get an error? Or are seeing some unexpected behavior? You should include whatever error you're seeing in the question and as much detail as possible.

Comment: @DanielRearden updated the post to include the error. This occurs when removing the parameters from "toggleSidebarMutation"

Comment: remove brackets, too .... `mutation { toggle...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying a field without any arguments, you should omit parentheses. In other words, you would just do

```
toggleSidebar
```

instead of

```
toggleSidebar()
```

The latter is not valid syntax in GraphQL.

Comment: I'm still getting an error for "Error: Network error: Cannot destructure undefined", is there an issue in the resolver using the empty argument brackets?

Comment: nevermind, just needed to update the arguments in the resolver to the name of empty arguments object, vs. having an empty destructuring object that i had before.